# Populating a dropdownlist with values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello I'm trying to make my dropdownlist to work but it seems harder than expected. I have 3 domain classes Member, Rental and Movie. My Idea was to make a dropdownlist that will show a specific users rented movies and when I select a movie in the dropdownlist and submit it I will get back the selected movie and I can set bool IsInStock to true.

So I made a viewmodel and a controller action but would like some help how to go forward with this. Now I get a dropdownlist with the users "Jan" rented movies but when I klick submit I would like to get the values back in order to set the IsInStock to true. I know I will need method to handle the POST values but I'm trying to make this work first.

```
public class Member
    {
        public virtual int MemberId { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Rental> Rentals { get; set; }
    }
 public class Rental
    {
        public virtual int RentalId { get; set; }
        public virtual int MovieId { get; set; }
        public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
        public virtual int MemberId { get; set; }
        public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
    }
  public class Movie
  {
    public virtual int MovieId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsInStock { get; set; }
  }
  public class RentalsViewModel
    {
        // Need something here.
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RentedMovies { get; set; }
    }
    public ActionResult ReturnMovie()
    {

        var rentedmovies = db.Rentals.Where(r => r.Member.Name == "Jan").ToList();

        var model = new RentalsViewModel()
        {

            RentedMovies = rentedmovies.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.MovieId.ToString(),
                Text = x.Movie.Name
            })
        };

        return View(model);
    }

// In the View

       @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RentedMovies, //Something here);
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</p>                                                                  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First parameter here:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RentedMovies, //Something here);
```

must be `int`, because you will send this value to the server:

```
public virtual int MovieId { get; set; }
```

So, your example could look like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RentedMovieId, Model.RentedMovies);
```

(Add property `RentedMovieId` to `RentalsViewModel`)